# Greasemonkey HTML multi line replacement

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to spoof page info using Greasemonkey to play a joke on my friend, but I don't seem to be able to get it to work.

The existing code looks something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">05/08</td>
    <td>06:12 PM</td>
    <td align="left"><a href="JavaScript:openPAB('Steve Blank')">Steve Blank</a></td>
    <td>3 Hours/47Min</td>
    <td>Biathlon</td>
    <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
```

and turn it into:

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">05/08</td>
    <td>10:00 PM</td>
    <td align="left"><a href="JavaScript:openPAB('Steve Blank')">Steve Blank</a></td>
    <td>Did not finish</td>
    <td>Disqualified</td>
    <td align="right"></td>
</tr>
```

So basically I want my friend to see his results as failing just to mess with him. He hasn't looked it up on his computer and I'd like to do this before he sees it. Since its ultimately HTML I assume I can drop the white space text, but I'm not sure about the special characters. Any ideas?

Comment: There is not enough information to select the right table cells to change.  We need to know the relation of these rows to the table and the relation of the table to the page. ... Paste source of the full, unedited page into http://pastebin.com and link to it here.

Comment: Ive tried using a specific line replace, and it works up until the java script part using: document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<td align=\"left\">05\/08<\/td>\n<td>06:12 PM<\/td>\n<td align=\"left\">\n< /g,"<td align=\"left\">05\/08<\/td><td>10:00 PM<\/td><td align=\"left\">\n");

as soon as I but the next < in it stops working

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, we do not write scripts from scratch on SO.

But, because this is for a good cause :) and is relatively simple, here is a start:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Improve X results
// @include         http://yourSite.com/somepath/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Get the table rows to change.  Warning: Insufficient detail given!
var tableRowsToFix  = $("table > tr:gt(0)");  //-- This must change to match actual page

/*--- For each row, adjust key cells, per...
    Column  Description         Change
    ------  -----------------   --------------------------
       1    Date                None.
       2    ¿Finish? Time?      Change to "10:00 PM"?
       3    <link>              None.
       4    Elapsed Time        Change to "Did not finish".
       5    Qualification       Change to "Disqualified".
       6    <blank>             None.
*/
tableRowsToFix.each ( function (J) {

    //--- Adjust column 2,  "Finish Time".
    this.cells[1].innerHTML = "10:00 PM";

    //--- Adjust column 4,  "Did not finish".
    this.cells[3].innerHTML = "10:00 PM";

    //--- Adjust column 5,  "Qualification".
    this.cells[4].innerHTML = "Disqualified";
} );
```

### Important!

The line to set `tableRowsToFix` is incorrect.  The question posted does not contain enough information to determine it accurately.   Link to the full page source on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) (or similar site).

Comment: I appreciate this everyone. Even setting it to the right row I still couldn't get it to work right, so I abandoned it for the time being, ultimately I checked the website again before he got home, and just used 2 instances of the code above to replace his name with another athlete that did not finish, and the other persons name with his. I wasn't in the room when he checked it, but he came out pissed off, until the rest of us couldn't control our laughter. I appreciate the work, and I am going to play with the code above to further my learning. Thank you all